# SwiftUI full screen transparent button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I try to add full screen transparent button:

```
Button(action: {
       // my action
}) {
    Rectangle()
     .opacity(0)
}
```

But in case `.opacity()` is less than 0.1 button action stop working. How to implement full screen transparent button?

Tested on iOS 14.3(Sim), iOS 14.2(iPhone X), Xcode 12.3

Comment: Would you not be better adding a tap gesture to the view?!

Comment: ^ e.g. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-view

Answer (score 5):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct DemoClearButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                print(">> transparent tapped")
            }
    }
}
```

*Note: probably in place of usage you'd wanted to add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`*

Comment: iOS 14.3(Sim), iOS 14.2(iPhone X), Xcode 12.3 `Color.clear` action not execute, any other color works perfect.

Comment: That sounds like a bug of 14.3

Comment: @SergeyDi It works as expected on iOS 14.3.

Comment: @SergeyDi I'm using Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3. Asperi's solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me the `.contentShape` didn't work. At least, it didn't prevent the view behind my button to also receive the touch.
But, and I feel dirty for suggesting this:

```swift
Button(action: {
    print("Yeahhh")
}) {
  Text("Yeah?").padding(64)
}
.background(LinearGradient(colors: [Color.clear], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
```

Adding a transparent `LinearGradient` did the trick for me.